# How to have Eclipse recognize dependencies from SBT

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I am trying to figure out how to make Eclipse recognize dependencies that are retrieved using SBT?  SBT download the correct dependencies and puts them in my ~/.ivy directory but eclipse doesn't see them.  Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: do you still accept the old answer over the newer ones?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for and I admit it is not elegant but it currently works for me, meaning that I think it takes less time for me to periodically do the following instead of researching and finding a more elegant solution.

I assume you are using the sbt-eclipse plugin ( https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse ). When I add new dependencies to my project ( which is actually pretty rare ) I simply regenerate my eclipse project files from the plugin. The downside of this is that I have a multiple module project and after I refresh the projects in eclipse I need to re-add the inter-project dependencies in the eclipse build path editor.

Like I mentioned it is pretty hacky but all in all I really don't loose that much time doing it. It's not pretty but it works.

Best of luck,
Andy

Comment: Yeah - this is what I do too. It's not as pretty as it might be, but it does work.

Comment: sbteclipse also correctly adds project dependencies if they are also set up in the sbt build file(s).

Comment: Any, Please let me know how sbteclipse fails for you at creating the inter-project dependencies. It should definitely work in the latest release (1.5) and the latest milestones (2.0.0-M1..M3) and snapshots (2.0.0-SNAPSHOTS). I suggest you use the sbt mailing list and use the prefix [sbteclipse] in the subject line. Thanks. Heiko

Comment: @HeikoSeeberger: Since the sbt mailing list is being phased out,could you please show us how to solve the OP's problem without hacking?

Answer (score 88):

If you are using sbteclipse plugin it's achievable in a simple way. In sbt type:

> reload
>   eclipse with-source=true

Then in eclipse, hit F5 on a project folder to refresh it. Or right-click and choose "Refresh". Just works.

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer instead of the one that is right now. Works like a charm!

Comment: +1 for with-source that permits to navigate the code of the dependencies I'm using from within Eclipse.

Comment: It works fine, when "Referenced Dependencies" is already shown in Eclipse - it adds the new ones. But if the project directly does not show "Referenced Dependencies" (yes, it's happening to me) this does not help.

Answer (score 14):

I use the [Apache IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) plugin for Eclipse, and I've had more luck with this approach. It's only [described in the old sbt docs](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/IntegrationSupport#IvyDE_approach), but works with sbt 0.11

First, install the IvyDE plugin in Eclipse and restart.

Run the sbt command `deliver-local` - this will create an XML ivy file of your dependencies.

In Eclipse, under your Project/Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries, click "Add Library" and choose "IvyDE Managed Dependencies" then select the file target/scala-2.9.1/ivy-*projectversion*.xml

When you add a new dependency to build.sbt, run the sbt commands `reload` and `deliver-local` again. Then right-click the Ivy library for your project in the Package Explorer - it will be called "target/scala-2.9.1/ivy-*projectversion*.xml [compile,test]", and click the second "Refresh" menu item (between "Refresh" and "Reload Settings" - *not* "F5 Refresh" ).

Comment: yes, this one is **"the" solution** here. What the OP wants is a native eclipse integration with SBT and this is the closest to it. With this one, eclipse actually **sees the IVY dependencies and uses them natively**.

Comment: this really solves my biggest pain point with eclipse/sbt and the eclipse scala IDE overall!

Answer (score 7):

In command prompt go to the project folder and type

```
sbt eclipse
```

This should generate the appropriate **.classpath** entries in eclipse project.

Go back to eclipse, select the project and **press f5**, this will reload the referenced libs.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is execute from your project home:

```
sbt "eclipse with-source=true"
```

or enter `sbt` console and write:

```
eclipse with-source=true
```

BTW: I don't know if from Jan '12 something has changed but now it seems much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

1) close project in Eclipse

2) in my file explorer, browse to my Eclipse project, make sure hidden files are visible

3) open .classpath in a simple text editor

4) copy the bottom entry. For example, in my current project, it is `<classpathentry path="/home/natalie/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.9.1/jars/scalatest_2.9.1-1.8.jar" kind="lib"></classpathentry>`

5) navigate to my .ivy folder, cache, then down to the library I have added via sbt

6) right click on jar file, select properties, copy the path and jar file name and replace it in the entry I copied in step 4

7) save .classpath

8) open my project on Eclipse

New dependency is now available in Eclipse.

Comment: the quesstion is how could someone do this automatically and not manually.