# How to have sbt recognize dependencies from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, sbt, ivy, tycho

I search some informations about the faisability of the exact inverse protocol described into this [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070336/how-to-have-eclipse-recognize-dependencies-from-sbt).

Using SBT, i want to compile and/or generate a release of an already existing software actively developed with Eclipse and **Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)** of Eclipse.

Users want to conserve the eclipse GUI tools to define dependencies for each plugins. But we also need a console tool like SBT. Do you think it exists some tools which can generate an SBT project based on plug-in dependencies written using eclipse PDE systems ?

I see that **tycho** plugin for eclipse can generate maven file, is it possible using SBT and IVY repository ( don't want .pom :( ) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have Eclipse recognize dependencies from SBT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070336/how-to-have-eclipse-recognize-dependencies-from-sbt)