# object typesafe is not a member of package com while importing com.typesafe

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

Facing the following issue in eclipse while importing the com.typesafe,

> Error : object typesafe is not a member of package com while importing
>   com.typesafe

simple.sbt files contains following,

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5"

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070336/how-to-have-eclipse-recognize-dependencies-from-sbt can help with this.

Comment: Check first that this compiles in the console. It might just be an IDE issue